# Converting a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| Pollutant | Delhi | London | Paris |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PM25 | 12 | 36 | 43 |
| Ozone | 120 | 34 | 42 |
| NO2 | 192 | 35 | 12 |

I'm trying to convert a pandas DataFrame like the one above to the one below. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

| Pollutant | Level | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PM25 | 12 | Delhi |
| Ozone | 120 | Delhi |
| NO2 | 192 | Delhi |
| PM25 | 36 | London |
| Ozone | 34 | London |
| NO2 | 35 | London |
| PM25 | 43 | Paris |
| Ozone | 42 | Paris |
| NO2 | 12 | Paris |

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and utilise the different parameters correctly which is exactly what you need:

```
>>> df.melt(id_vars=['Pollutant'],value_name='Level',var_name='City')

  Pollutant    City  Level
0      PM25   Delhi     12
1     Ozone   Delhi    120
2       NO2   Delhi    192
3      PM25  London     36
4     Ozone  London     34
5       NO2  London     35
6      PM25   Paris     43
7     Ozone   Paris     42
8       NO2   Paris     12
```

`value_name` will give a name to the column where your values will be.

Same logic applies to `var_name`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked perfectly!